# Schedule a trigger

Tags: trigger, scheduled-apex

I have a date field on my page, and I want to invoke the trigger at the particular date and time that user selects, can anyone suggest me a way to do it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have a field that is a time date field
2. Create a workflow rule to run when created and every time edited to meet criteria with the criteria being that the field (#1) is Not Equal To (Leave value field blank)
3. Create a checkbox on the record
4. Set the time based field update to run 0 hours after the date/time field #1 and the update sets the checkbox field in #3 to true
5. In the trigger (before update is best if possible), check to see if the checkbox field is true and if so, run your code, set the checkbox to false, and clear out the date/time #1 field

Lots of steps to accomplish this but this should do what you specifically asked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is actually what you want.  I think you actually want to schedule a job to fire at a particular time for a particular record?  (A trigger can be used to create this scheduled job or any controller, but a trigger is not required)

```
ScheduleJob sched = new Schedule();
schedule.recordid = yourObj.Id;
String schedule = yourDate.second().format() + ' ' + yourDate.minute().format() + ' ' + yourDate.hour().format() + ' ' + yourDate.day().format() + ' ' + yourDate.month().format() + ' ? ' + ' ' + String.valueOf(yourDate.year());
System.schedule('record invoked: ' + yourObj.Name, schedule, sched);
```

---

```
global class ScheduleJob implements Scheduleable
{
  public Id recordId;

  global void execute(scheduleableContext SC)
  {
    if (recordId != null)
    {
      ...//do work
    }
  }
}
```